# Duplicate CSS rule out put when using attribute selector containing slashes and colon

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, node-sass, scss-mixins

I've got a pretty basic selector that contains some slashes and a colon:

```
[data-sitemap-state="/register/:/"] {
  @include typography;
}
```

I've using `gulp-sass`, which as far as I know uses `node-sass`, and therefore `lib-sass` under the hood.

The mixin (`typography`) looks like this:

```
@mixin typography {

  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25em;

}
```

When the SCSS is built the following CSS is generated:

```
[data-sitemap-state="/register/:/"],
[data-sitemap-state="/register/.\:/"] {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

I don't understand why the additional selector is generated:

```
[data-sitemap-state="/register/.\:/"]
```

Particularly `.\:/`

I've tried escaping the colon character and using the unicode/hex values for the colon and the same CSS is generated regardless.

I was expecting this output:

```
[data-sitemap-state="/register/:/"] {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this additional rule is created for IE8 support.